# Percent encoding in Ruby

Tags: ruby, percent-encoding

In Ruby, I get the percent-encoding of 'ä' by

```
require 'cgi'
CGI.escape('ä')
=> "%C3%A4"
```

The same with

```
'ä'.unpack('H2' * 'ä'.bytesize)
=> ["c3", "a4"]
```

I have two questions:

1. What is the reverse of the first operation? Shouldn't it be

   ```
   ["c3", "a4"].pack('H2' * 'ä'.bytesize)
   => "\xC3\xA4"
   ```
2. For my application I need 'ä' to be encoded as "%E4" which is the hex-value of 'ä'.ord. Is there any Ruby-method for it?

Comment: Why would you need "%e4"? I couldn't convert it back to that unicode char.

Comment: I think you need to understand that decimal values 128-255 do not uniquely represent a particular character, unless you also specify the encoding that goes along with it. It looks like you're using ISO 8859-1?

Comment: Perhaps helpful: `"\xE4".encode('utf-8','iso-8859-1')` produces `"ä"`. `"ä".encode('iso-8859-1').codepoints.first.to_s(16)` returns `"e4"`.

Comment: A shorter version of the above `URI::escape('ä'.encode('iso-8859-1'))` (you need to `require 'uri'`.

Comment: I wanted "%E4" since this is what my email client displays correctly as an 'ä' while  "%C3%A4" is displayed as "Ã¤" in the mail-address. My strings in ruby are utf-8. So conversion to iso-8859-1 may be a solution for this particular email client and I have to test it with others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, equating the character ä as the codepoint 228 (0xE4) implies that you're dealing with the [ISO 8859-1 character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1).

So, you need to tell Ruby what encoding you want for your string.

```
str1 = "Hullo ängstrom" # uses whatever encoding is current, generally utf-8
str2 = str1.encode('iso-8859-1')
```

Then you can encode it as you like:

```
require 'cgi'
s2c = CGI.escape str2
#=> "Hullo+%E4ngstrom" 

require 'uri'
s2u = URI.escape str2
#=> "Hullo%20%E4ngstrom"
```

Then, to reverse it, you must first (a) unescape the value, and then (b) turn the encoding back into what you're used to (likely UTF-8), **telling Ruby what character encoding it should interpret the codepoints as**:

```
s3a = CGI.unescape(s2c)  #=> "Hullo \xE4ngstrom"
puts s3a.encode('utf-8','iso-8859-1')
#=> "Hullo ängstrom"

s3b = URI.unescape(s2u)  #=> "Hullo \xE4ngstrom"
puts s3b.encode('utf-8','iso-8859-1')
#=> "Hullo ängstrom"
```

Comment: Note that `"\xE4"` is not a string with 4 characters; it is a string with a single character whose codepoint is decimal 228 (hex E4). Ruby displays `\xE4` in the `inspect` version of the string because that codepoint is not valid in UTF-8, which happens to be my default string encoding.